# (ANDROID) How to POST JSON to server by enter our username and password (Login Page)?

Tags: java, android, json, authentication, post

i need help from how to input our username and password and post them to my server. i try few way its no working, tried .getText() and .toString() but still working. tried few solution from other tutorial web get nothing too. Please help. Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


String etUsername;
String etPassword;
Button btSubmit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etUsername = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_username)).getText().toString();
    etPassword = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_password)).getText().toString();
    btSubmit = findViewById(R.id.bt_submit);

    TextView TextViewResult;
    TextViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    btSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MainActivity.this
                );
```

i add here

```
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            // Json here
            try {
             
                jsonObject.put("app_id", "123");
                jsonObject.put("username",etUsername);
                jsonObject.put("password",etPassword);
                jsonObject.put("firebase_token", "123");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonObject.toString());
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("")
                    .post(body)
                    .build();

            Response response = null;
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String myResponse = response.body().string();

                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                TextViewResult.setText(myResponse);
                            }
                        });


                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    );


    }

    }
```

no error for my coding after running it, just i cant get my correct data POST to server. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Done

```
EditText etUsername,etPassword;

etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);


 try {
                
                jsonObject.put("app_id", "Cu7HAc8Udro3rePhIPoBrubLBr7hljIcopICu8uGlwlSwAprOprlYOd9aXAchugu");
                jsonObject.put("username",etUsername.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("password",etPassword.getText().toString());
                jsonObject.put("firebase_token", "abc123");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```